# Sign in with apple returns no credentials

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

Apple sign in is not working. The delegate `didCompleteWithAuthorization` is getting fired. But the credentials are returning `nil`.

```
if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
        print(appleIDCredential.fullName)
        print(appleIDCredential.email)
}
```

Both `fullName` and `email` are returning `nil` values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You’ll need to post your full code see we can see what’s going on. Are you even requesting the name and email for example..

Comment: let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        print(appleIDProvider)
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.nonce = self.sha256(nonce)

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()

This is the code

Answer (score 0):

> This behaves correctly, user info is only sent in the
>   ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential upon initial user sign up. Subsequent
>   logins to your app using Sign In with Apple with the same account do
>   not share any user info and will only return a user identifier in the
>   ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential. It is recommened that you securely
>   cache the initial ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential containing the user
>   info until you can validate that an account has succesfully been
>   created on your server.

Check: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121496#379297

Comment: Yeah, but I removed the user details and authentication from Firebase before testing again. When I ran the app in the simulator, it worked fine. But when I ran the app in the phone, it gave me error